# Capturing webcam stream under linux

Tags: linux, webcam, v4l

I'm trying to get images from a minoru3d webcam, which is actually two Vimicro webcams plus a USB hub in a single package. The problem is, opencv always takes streams in maximum resolution, making simultaneous capture from two webcams impossible(due to usb constraints). How do I set resolution or FPS? For some reason, opencv calls

```
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320 );
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240 );
```

don't work. I don't need to work with opencv, any other library doing the same job is good for me. The webcam uses uvc drivers from kernel 2.6.30, with v4l2. I tried the custom module here: http://linuxtv.org/hg/~pinchartl/uvcvideo on my Ubuntu box with 2.6.27 kernel.

Comment: Have you read this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287/increasing-camera-capture-resolution-in-opencv

You could also try setting the resolution with v4l2-ctl.

Comment: You could also try posting on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [luvcview](http://www.quickcamteam.net/software/linux/v4l2-software/luvcview) and [v4l2cam](http://code.google.com/p/libv4l2cam/) for my purposes. [2](http://code.google.com/p/libv4l2cam/) is specifically written for the Minoru.