# Decrease image resolution in OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, resolution

I'm using OpenCV to capture images from A4Tech camera. When I try to decrease image resolution, image assertion fails:

```
CvCapture *camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(1); // 0 is index of Laptop integrated camera
cvSetCaptureProperty( camera, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160 );
cvSetCaptureProperty( camera, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 140 );
assert(camera); // This is passed
while(true)
{
    // ....
    IplImage * image=cvQueryFrame(camera);
    assert(image); // This fails. (Line 71 is here)
    // ....
}
```

Output is:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Initial Capture Error: Unable to load initial memory buffers.
udpits: main.cpp:71: int main(int, char**): Assertion `image' failed.
Aborted
```

Comment: Does the camera support that resolution? Does it work with a different resolution?

Comment: @LiMuBei yes. In Cheese camera setting there are 5 different resolutions for the camera.

Comment: But do they work when you set them?

Comment: Yes they work properly in cheese.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be doing it the right way, but [OpenCV is known to have issues doing this kind of stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290/176769). Are you sure your camera supports 160x140? Cheese says my camera supports **160x120**, but when I select this format nothing seems to change.

One thing though, it's best to always check the return of OpenCV calls, for instance:

```
CvCapture *camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
if (!camera)
{
    // print error and exit
}
```

One thing you could do is [resize](http://linuxconfig.org/resize-an-image-with-opencv-cvresize-function) the captured frame to the resolution you want. It's not ideal, I know, your CPU is going to do this task and therefore there will be some performance cost to your application, but if you need the image to be of a certain size and OpenCV is not playing nice there ain't much you can do, unless you are willing to make a surgery on OpenCV.

**EDIT:**

One thing you should do is check whether these values were really set. So after setting them, retrieve them with `cvGetCaptureProperty()`.

Comment: I can't do resize... My processor is vortex86DX and with 85% usage I can not fetch more than 18 frames per second (with no algorithm applied on images!).

Comment: In that case, prepare to get your hands dirty and dig into OpenCV.

Comment: Maybe @mevatron has something to say about this. New guy, very energetic on OpenCV, will probably get the silver badge on OpenCV way before I do.