# Opensource Webcam Library

Tags: c++, windows, video-streaming, webcam, frame-rate

Is there any opensource library which can be used to decrease frame rate or resolution of webcam on windows platform? I need to limit bandwidth utilized by high resolution webcam connected to USB port.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) fullfills your requirements.

See the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339077/decrease-image-resolution-in-opencv) about decreasing the resolution and read the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) documentation.