# How to Reduce the Resolution of an Image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

So, I have an image from a digital scanner, its resolution is 26 Megapixel.
I want to reduce the resolution of the image to 5 Megapixel.

Is it possible to reduce the resolution of an image without damaging the contents?

If yes, how to reduce it in OpenCV implementation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: Mean this or something else? Please be more specific. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339077/decrease-image-resolution-in-opencv)

Comment: What do you mean by "without damaging the contents"?

Comment: no, that's not what I meant before, I've already had an image scanned with a digital scanner. There is no camera involved. I just need to reduce the resolution of an image.

Comment: I'm working on a OCR project with a scanner, so what I meant by "without damaging the contents" is that whenever I reduce the resolution of an image, will it damage the characters in the image?

Comment: Do you mean to shrink the image with cv::resize? There would be some lose of data, maybe that is harmful for your content.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [cv2::resize()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#cv2.resize)

```
resize(src, dst, Size(), factor, factor, interpolation);
```

here, `interpolation` can be selected as `cv::INTER_LANCZOS4` to obtain best interpolation results.

`factor` is the sampling ratio and in order to transform from 26mp to 5mp you may need it to be 2.28

Downsampling always introduces some information and detail loss.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I have been looking for.

Comment: For shrinking, the 'factor' will be <1, and you can instead set factor =0 and supply the desired output size as the third parameter. INTER_LANCZOS4 doesn't really make any difference for shrinks. You will get about the same result as INTER_AREA, neither of which are very good (quite a lot of aliasing). This is a hole in OpenCV - no really good method for 1-step shrink (the cubic and lanczos filters don't adapt properly to shrink). You could try shrinking to 2x desired size with INTER_AREA, and then use pyrDown to get the final result. Will have much less aliasing but maybe a bit blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the resolution of the image is the very definition of damaging the content. Lossless image compression does not reduce the resolution of the image. That said 5 megapixels is still a very high resolution and more then most applications should require. The exceptions might be scientific and medical applications. I would simply ensure that you are preserving the original until you know you can work with the result and choose your image compression method carefully to reduce artifacts.