# Resizing non uniform images with precise face location

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, crop

I work at a studio that does school photos and we are trying to make a script to eliminate the job of cropping each photo to a template. The photos we work with are fairly uniform but they vary in resolution and head position a bit. I took up the mantle of trying to write the script with my fairly limited Python knowledge and through a lot of trial and error and online resources I think I have got most of the way there.

At the moment I am trying to figure out the best way to have the image crop from the NumPy array with the head where I want and I just cant find a good flexible solution. The head needs to be positioned slightly differently for pose 1 and pose 2 so its needs to be easy to change on the fly (Probably going to implement some sort of simple GUI to input stuff like that, but for now I can just change the code).

I also need to be able to change the output resolution of the photo so they are all uniform (2000x2500). Anyone have any ideas?

At the moment this is my current code, it just saves the detected face square:

```
import cv2
import os.path
import glob

# Cascade path
cascPath = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'

# Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

#Check for output folder and create if its not there
if not os.path.exists('output'):
    os.makedirs('output')

# Read Images
images = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for c, i in enumerate(images):
    image = cv2.imread(i, 1)

    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find face(s) using cascade
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,  # size of groups
        minNeighbors=5,  # How many groups around are detected as face for it to be valid
        minSize=(500, 500)  # Min size in pixels for face
    )

    # Outputs number of faces found in image
    print('Found {0} faces!'.format(len(faces)))

    # Places a rectangle on face
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        imgCrop = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]

    if len(faces) > 0:
        #Saves Images to output folder with OG name
        cv2.imwrite('output/'+ i, imgCrop)
```

I can crop using it like this:

```
    # Crop Padding
    left = 300
    right = 300
    top = 400
    bottom = 1000
    
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        imgCrop = image[y-top:y+h+bottom, x-left:x+w+right]
```

but that outputs pretty random resolutions and changes based on the image resolution

Answer (score 0):

***TL;DR***

- To set a new resolution with the dimension, you can use `cv2.resize`. There may be a pixel loss so you can use the interpolation method.
- The newly resized image may be in `BGR` format, so you may need to convert to RGB format.

```
cv2.resize(src=crop, dsize=(2000, 2500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
crop = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Make sure the cropped image is in RGB format
cv2.imwrite("image-1.png", crop)
```

***Suggestion:***

- One approach is using python's [face-recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) library.
- The approach is using two sample images for training.
- Predict the next image based on training images.

For instance, The followings are the training images:

[image] [image]

We want to predict the faces in the below image:

[image]

When we get the facial encodings of the training images and apply to the next image:

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
first_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("images/ex.jpg")
first_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(first_image)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
second_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("images/index.jpg")
sec_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(second_image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    first_face_encoding,
    sec_face_encoding
]

print('Learned encoding for', len(known_face_encodings), 'images.')

# Load an image with an unknown face
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("images/babes.jpg")

# Find all the faces and face encodings in the unknown image
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(unknown_image)
face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image, face_locations)

# Convert the image to a PIL-format image so that we can draw on top of it with the Pillow library
# See http://pillow.readthedocs.io/ for more about PIL/Pillow
pil_image = Image.fromarray(unknown_image)
# Create a Pillow ImageDraw Draw instance to draw with
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)

# Loop through each face found in the unknown image
for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
    face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
    best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
    draw.rectangle(((left, top), (right, bottom)), outline=(0, 0, 255), width=5)

# Remove the drawing library from memory as per the Pillow docs
del draw

# Display the resulting image
plt.imshow(pil_image)
plt.show()
```

The output will be:

[image]

The above is my suggestion. When you create a new resolution with the current image, there will be a pixel loss. Therefore you need to use an ***interpolation*** method.

For instance: after finding the face locations, select the coordinates in the original image.

```
# Add after draw.rectangle function.
crop = unknown_image[top:bottom, left:right]
```

Set new resolution with the size 2000 x 2500 and interpolation with `CV2.INTERN_LANCZOS4`.

Possible Question: Why `CV2.INTERN_LANCZOS4`?

Of course, you can select whatever you like, but [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343469/how-to-reduce-the-resolution-of-an-image-in-opencv/17344437) `CV2.INTERN_LANCZOS4` was suggested.

```
cv2.resize(src=crop, dsize=(2000, 2500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
```

Save the image

```
crop = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Make sure the cropped image is in RGB format
cv2.imwrite("image-1.png", crop)
```

Outputs are around 4.3 MB Therefore I can't display in here.

From the final result, we clearly see and identify faces. The library precisely finds the faces in the image.

Here what you can do:

- Either you can use the training images of your own-set, or you can use the example above.
- Apply the face-recognition function for each image, using the trained face-locations and save the results in the directory.

Comment: Haarcascade features are old and robust techniques. This technique may improve the accuracy of your work. I suggest just give a chance.

Comment: This seems to pose the same problem I currently have. The output ends up being a random resolution and aspect ratio.

Comment: @Tristan.Beer I've updated my answer. You can check the TL;DR section.

Comment: Ok, I kinda like this method better the openCV detection. Is there a way to get the face position in the original image? So if it finds a face it can tell me where say the center of the face box is in pixels? This way I could take that value and possibly crop accordingly (say if head was to low crop top of image more then bottom to get the center in the right position ) if I understand correctly.

Comment: never mind, box 0, 0 is stored in the x, y variables. I will give that implementation a shot!

Comment: When you finished the implementation, Please tell me the result. I wonder whether it is working or not.

Comment: Just got everything working in opencv, I found it to be a bit faster working single threaded, however I might try and get multi threading working with the python face-recognition library to see if that speeds it up. Thank you so much for all your help, its been invaluable!

Comment: Glad if I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

here is how I got it to crop how I wanted, this is added right below the "output number of faces" function

```
#Get the face postion and output values into variables, might not be needed but I did it
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        xdis = x
        ydis = y
        w = w
        h = h

    #Get scale value by dividing wanted head hight by detected head hight
    ws = 600/w
    hs = 600/h

    #scale image to get head to right size, uses bilinear interpolation by default
    scale = cv2.resize(image,(0,0),fx=hs,fy=ws)

    #calculate head postion for given values
    sxdis = int(xdis*ws) #applying scale to x distance and turning it into a integer
    sydis = int(ydis*hs) #applying scale to y distance and turning it into a integer
    sycent = sydis+300 #adding half head hight to get center
    ystart = sycent-700 #subtract where you want the head center to be in pixels, this is for the vertical
    yend = ystart+2500 #Add whatever you want vertical resolution to be
    xcent = sxdis+300 #adding half head hight to get center
    xstart = xcent-1000 #subtract where you want the head center to be in pixels, this is for the horizontal
    xend = xstart+2000 #add whatever you want the horizontal resolution to be

    #Crop the image
    cropped = scale[ystart:yend, xstart:xend]
```

Its a mess but it works exactly how I wanted it to work.
ended up going with openCV instead of switching to python-Recognition because of speed but I might switch over if I can get multithreading to work in python-recognition.