# Increasing camera capture resolution in OpenCV from Python

Tags: video, opencv, resolution, capture

Its 2012 and cv2 is here.
This old post shows you how to change camera resolution in versions of opencv around 1.1
[camera capture in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287/increasing-camera-capture-resolution-in-opencv)
but these functions are not available in cv2 or its enclosed cv2.cv module
(opencv 2.4.1 is latest to-date)

Does anyone know how to change camera resolutions from python for opencv ?
I am not looking for a c++ solution but instead one that is accessible from the python (2.7) that cv2 is delivered in. Importing a separate module is acceptable.

As stated elsewhere the VideoCapture.set functions do not work.

Comment: There is a new answer in the link you posted. It does what you want in python.

Comment: This just worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14510607/770443

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Camera Parameters in OpenCV/Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python)