# OpenCV camera properties dialog

Tags: opencv

A few weeks ago I saw on the internet that you could display a small dialog/ menu with a few properties of the camera. In this menu the user can change the contrast, brightness...but I can not find it anymore. Does somebody know the code to get this dialog?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't offer this functionality. Different camera manufacturers have different API's for accessing and changing camera parameters. There is no standard way to do this. So, you can try to access your camera settings using its API and then you can write your own GUI dialog window (for example, using [QT library](http://qt-project.org/search/tag/library)) to view/change the parameters.

Comment: I am sure there was such a dialog of OpenCV! I only do not find/ know the code anymore...

Comment: my guess is that it was a demo of OpenCV GUI, where user can change brightness/ contrast of an image. However, it may have been done by processing the image, as opposed to changing camera parameters.

Comment: you probably should be able to look it up in OpenCV documentation if it exists.

Comment: OpenCV has `C++: bool VideoCapture::set(int propId, double value)`, which can set properties, such as `CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS`, but I couldn't find a dialog (one method call) version of it.

Comment: I only know it was posted on stackoverflow :P

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11433221/1121420) might me helpful. I'm sure that currently you can't do it with just a couple of function calls in OpenCV. If you find the solution let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It was a dialog with a few trackbars to change contrast/ brightness/ sharpness... Or is it possible that the VideoInput lib this has?

Comment: No, there isn't a trivial method in OpenCV. One would need to create a Qt dialog window and trackbars (`createTrackbar()`), etc, and then to use some method to set camera parameters.

Comment: I think it is: VI.showSettingsWindow(device1); of the videoInput library. I will try it tomorrow. My fault that I thought OpenCV contains this window.

Comment: glad you found it. I think I answered your question though, right?

Answer (score 12):

Set the property `CV_CAP_PROP_SETTINGS` with any value.

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0); 
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_SETTINGS, 0); //opens camera properties dialog
```

Comment: That's a very good tip. I tried to find out the parameter ranges for the different ``CV_CAP_PROP_XX`` manually, but with this dialogue things are much easier!

Comment: This works.  Had to define the constant in C#  
See  https://github.com/Kawaian/OpenCvSharp/blob/master/opencv/3.2/include/opencv2/videoio/videoio_c.h