# Open CV Capture blurred

Tags: opencv

I am using opencv to capture from an IP camera and can capture the feed fine.

The feed is of a door entrance, and I am capturing people coming in the door.
However, when some people move too quickly, that person becomes slightly blurred due to the motion.

Does anyone know how to capture a frame differently or how to run an algorithm to fix the image?

Here is a sample image:
[image: sample image]

I have hidden the face of the image but you should get the idea.
As you can see the gate, which is stationary, is in focus.

Here is the key part of the frame capture code (obviously there is more)

```
this->_cvCap = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
IplImage * image = cvQueryFrame(this->_cvCap);
cvSaveImage(filenamename, image);
```

Answer (score 4):

The blurring is likely due to low shutter speed (high integration time) which gives a long exposure time.
You can theoretically set this using OpenCV with the [cvSetCaptureProperty](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) function.
Be aware though, that this is not supported for a lot of cameras.

Here is a related question on SO: [Setting Camera Parameters in OpenCV/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python)

Comment: Thanks seems to work with my webcam. I will now test with the IP camera and let you know.