# Thorlabs camera DCU223M with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I tried to interface a Thorlabs camera DCU223M with opencv 2.4.5 and python 2.7 (under windows 7). I notice that people managed to interface a DC1545M. See: [Setting Camera Parameters in OpenCV/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python)

I used the same procedure but it does not work. An error occurs while cv2.imshow is invoked. 
ret=0 and img is none... that is the main reason. What can I do to interface this camera?

Thank you in advance,

stéphane