# OpenCV - changing camera resolution in Java

Tags: java, opencv, camera, resolution

It seems that the standard method for setting the resolution on a webcam in Java opencv doesn't work. I do the following:

```
VideoCapture v = new VideoCapture();

boolean wset = v.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
boolean hset = v.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 800);

System.out.println(wset);
System.out.println(hset);

v.open(1);
```

Which prints:

```
> false
> false
```

...and doesn't change the camera resolution. It appears to be stuck at 640x480. I know that the  camera is not at fault because I can successfully set the resolution to 1280x800 using the C++ bindings.

Also - `v.getSupportedPreviewSizes()` doesn't work. It returns an error:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: getting property #1025 is not supported
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

You need to open the camera first then set it. I tried it before camera.open(0) and it just returns to standard settings, but when try setting after camera.open(0) it works.

so do this in your code

```
v.open(1)
boolean wset = v.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
boolean hset = v.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 800);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your camera to run, You first need to open your capture device:

```
    VideoCapture v = new VideoCapture(0);
```

`//add 0 as paramater in the constructor.This is the index of your capture device.`

```
    boolean wset = v.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
    boolean hset = v.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 800);

    System.out.println(wset);
    System.out.println(hset);
```

And v.getSupportedPreviewSizes() doesnt work use this instead:

```
v.get(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //to get the actual width of the camera
v.get(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);//to get the actual height of the camera
```

Comment: Oh, I have been able to see the video - I just didn't mark that step. I'll edit it. The problem is still there. Also, every time I do `v.get(...)` it returns 640 and 480, regardless of what I have set it to.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass camera number with the constructor and set width and height...

```
webCamera = new VideoCapture(0);
webCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
webCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
```

There you go....

Answer (score 1):

Instead use Highgui to set resolution, use property ID, where 3 is to WIDTH and 4 is to HEIGHT, so your code will be like:

```
VideoCapture v = new VideoCapture();
boolean wset = v.set(3, RESOLUTION_WIDTH);
boolean hset = v.set(4, RESOLUTION_HEIGHT);

System.out.println(wset);
System.out.println(hset);

v.open(cameraID);
```

Other property ids you can find at [Setting Camera Parameters in OpenCV/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 1):

On the new OpenCV 4.5 you should use something like:

```
import org.opencv.videoio.Videoio;
...
this.capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
this.capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
```