# increase resolution for camera in opencv

Tags: java, opencv, camera, resolution, android-camera2

I have a device which is of 13MP camera, my default camera resolution is 1280x720, as a 13MP camera can give more higher resolutions than 1280x720 I want to increase it than my default value?

I have tried to check if my device supports larger resolutions with `chameraCharacteristics, SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP`   and i got output as: 4224x3136,4096x3072, 1920x1088, 4096x3072, 1920x1088, 1920x1080,1280x720, 720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144 and the view size of my device is 1280x800, most of the articles, and posts say that opencv restricts the camera resolution upto the viewSize?
can someone please help on how i can override this and increase the resolution of my camera?

Thanks.

Comment: You may better tell what is your camera (bayer, YUV, ...) and how it is connected to jetson (MIPI/CSI or USB). For a sensor in /dev/video0, you may see the available modes from `v4l2-ctl -d0 --list-formats-ext`. Depending on this from opencv you may use V4L or GSTREAMER backend for getting frames into OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

After opening the camera, you should be able to edit the properties at your liking with the [set](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/org/opencv/videoio/VideoCapture.html#set(int,double)) method of VideoCapture:

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0); //0 is there to avoid camera.open(0)

boolean setWidth = camera.set(3, 4096); //CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH = 3
boolean setHeigth = camera.set(4, 3072); //CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT = 4
```

As stated in the linked page the set method returns

> **true** if the property is supported by backend used by the VideoCapture instance.
> *Note: Even if it returns true this doesn't ensure that the property value has been accepted by the capture device*.

You can find the flags/ids for all the properties in [org.opencv.videoio.Videoio](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/constant-values.html#org.opencv.videoio.Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

Comment: Why would you put the `CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` in a comment, instead of using the named constant directly in the code instead of those magic numbers? That's a terrible example to set.

Comment: @DanMašek it was just to give a quick copy pastable try, not knowing which parts of the library were already in the project. The comments were there for that particular reason, to not go crazy chasing magic numbers. I linked the doc with all the flags to correctly implement what's needed. However I appreciate the tip, I'm still studying, and that's one of my very first answers.

Comment: I tried to use VideoCapture and have set the values to my desired resolution, but when I tried to print setWidth and setHeight, to check if the values were set or not it was returning "false" value" and I am sure that my camera can support this resolution! Can you please help if I am missing anything here? I am new to open cv camera!
[referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066329/opencv-changing-camera-resolution-in-java?rq=1) for some other videoCapture solutions as well to find a solution but those solutions were not working for me !

Comment: @Ani Since the returning value is false, it's the backend that doesn't support that resolution. If I recall correctly cv2 uses MSMF by default, so try changing the VideoCapture to this `VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0,Videoio.CAP_DSHOW);` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Greenylie tried changing the VideoCapture to `VideoCapture camera = new `VideoCapture(0,Videoio.CAP_DSHOW);` but when I print the the setWidth and setHeight it still returns me "false", does that mean I cannot set the resolution to a higher resolution? above my default 1280x720? 
Thanks.

Comment: @Ani Can I ask what device is it? So we can understand which backend to use

Comment: so I am testing on a 13MP device, But I am not capturing any video in my app, My app only supports clicking images, and I am trying to increase the resolution of the images captured by the camera! can u please clarify if VideoCapture support increasing resolution to both images and video as well?

Comment: @Ani Usually capturing images with cv2 is just saving the current frame of the VideoCapture. Apart from the resolution, do you have a working code to retrieve the image? We can try to work on that, if so.