# Python, OpenCV : Capture Images from WebCam

Tags: python, opencv, image-capture

I have a Logitech C920 hooked to my PC and am trying to use it to click pictures using OpenCV.

I know that I can capture images using :

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
s, im = cam.read() # captures image
cv2.imshow("Test Picture", im) # displays captured image
cv2.imwrite("test.bmp",im) # writes image test.bmp to disk
```

But it get me the 15MP still photography that my camera is capable of. What I get from above is far inferior to what I can expect if I `click` pictures.

So, is there a way to take pictures (like it can be done in the official WebCam software) ?

Comment: Hi, have you seen this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11420748/5066845)? If your camera is compatible, you will be able to adjust the settings to create a larger/clearer picture. I'll post a sample program to read out the current settings of the camera and an example of how to set the camera parameters.

Answer (score 8):

After testing with this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11420748/5066845) as a guide, I wrote the following program to check my camera's settings (Logitech S7500 USB Webcam). I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4.6 on Windows 7.

Hopefully you can use this code as a guide to modify the setting on your camera to get the resolution (or close to it) you need (using the `set()` function from OpenCV.)

If you get all 0.0 as the values for each camera setting, then you may not have the ability to adjust the camera settings. I experienced this when running this program on my laptop's built-in webcam.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import cv2


def main(argv):
    #capture from camera at location 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # Change the camera setting using the set() function
    # cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, -6.0)
    # cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN, 4.0)
    # cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, 144.0)
    # cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST, 27.0)
    # cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_HUE, 13.0) # 13.0
    # cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION, 28.0)
    # Read the current setting from the camera
    test = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
    ratio = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO)
    frame_rate = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
    width = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    height = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    brightness = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS)
    contrast = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST)
    saturation = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION)
    hue = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_HUE)
    gain = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN)
    exposure = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE)
    print("Test: ", test)
    print("Ratio: ", ratio)
    print("Frame Rate: ", frame_rate)
    print("Height: ", height)
    print("Width: ", width)
    print("Brightness: ", brightness)
    print("Contrast: ", contrast)
    print("Saturation: ", saturation)
    print("Hue: ", hue)
    print("Gain: ", gain)
    print("Exposure: ", exposure)
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("input", img)

        key = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if key == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()


#   0  CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC Current position of the video file in milliseconds.
#   1  CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES 0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.
#   2  CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO Relative position of the video file
#   3  CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH Width of the frames in the video stream.
#   4  CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT Height of the frames in the video stream.
#   5  CV_CAP_PROP_FPS Frame rate.
#   6  CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC 4-character code of codec.
#   7  CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT Number of frames in the video file.
#   8  CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT Format of the Mat objects returned by retrieve() .
#   9 CV_CAP_PROP_MODE Backend-specific value indicating the current capture mode.
#   10 CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS Brightness of the image (only for cameras).
#   11 CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST Contrast of the image (only for cameras).
#   12 CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION Saturation of the image (only for cameras).
#   13 CV_CAP_PROP_HUE Hue of the image (only for cameras).
#   14 CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN Gain of the image (only for cameras).
#   15 CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE Exposure (only for cameras).
#   16 CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB Boolean flags indicating whether images should be converted to RGB.
#   17 CV_CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE Currently unsupported
#   18 CV_CAP_PROP_RECTIFICATION Rectification flag for stereo cameras (note: only supported by DC1394 v 2.x backend currently)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

[Here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/34461/how-to-set-camera-resolution-webcam-with-opencv/) is a link to an OpenCV question about this topic and the [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set)

Comment: I am able to record full HD video and pull images off it, that is sorted. What I wished for was a more natural way to click pictures. I hoped for something like : `img = cv2.ClickImage(1, quality='15MP')`

Comment: You'll probably have to check the OpenCV documentation, this is the best way (and simplest) that I've found that works for me.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'` for `cv2.cv`

Comment: Hi, which version of opeCV are you using? Thing have changed for OpenCV 3. If you have a newer version, this might help ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33199152/5066845