# OpenCV webcam image broken

Tags: python, opencv, arm, webcam, odroid

I wrote a script in Python3 and OpenCV 3.1 for timelapse photos on Odroid C1:

Unfortunately sometimes images from the webcam are messed up:
Here's are some example photographs.

[image] 
[image]

And here's the source code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import datetime
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # USB webcam

cap.set(3,2304.0) #  Resolution: Width
cap.set(4,1296.0) # Resolution: Height
cap.set(5, 6) #webcam capture FPS 
print(str(cap.get(3)),str(cap.get(4)),str(cap.get(5)))


def captureImage():
         ret, frame = cap.read()
         curr_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
         filename = 'littleGarden_'+curr_time +'.jpg'
         file_to_save = folder_to_save + filename
         cv2.imwrite(file_to_save,frame)
         print("File saved ", file_to_save)


ret, frame = cap.read()
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    captureImage()
    time.sleep(delay)

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For reference, the first argument in the cap.set() command refers to the enumeration of the camera properties, listed below:

```
0. CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC Current position of the video file in milliseconds.
1. CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES 0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.
2. CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO Relative position of the video file
3. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH Width of the frames in the video stream.
4. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT Height of the frames in the video stream.
5. CV_CAP_PROP_FPS Frame rate.
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not working with a video file.
It is not clear to me what options you are setting but it could be a problem with your `set` calls on your `VideoCapture` object.
Keep in mind that you are working with a camera so there is no index to skip if I remember correctly.

EDIT:
Jack, I think you should be able to access the correct constants by using `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS` etc.
Assuming your camera driver implemented these ioctls you would receive 3 frames per seconds. However only one picture per second would be written by the `imwrite()` call as you are overwriting the other two.

You should test your received `Mat` without writing them down directly with the highgui `imshow` if possible. Test that without setting anything and report back.

Comment: I've removed that part, but still it didn't get better. I used info from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

It happens for first few frames, after starting a stream. I will suggest discard first few frames, and then start reading the frames.

```
for discard_frame in range(20):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    captureImage()
    time.sleep(delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

USB compatibility should be 1.1. If you are using VMware

[image]