# Resizing video resolution in OpenCV python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I want to reduce the resolution of video that I am getting from my webcam to half(i.e from 640x480 to 320x240) but I am getting error.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,320)
cap.set(4,240)

while(True):

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error that I am getting is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Nemi\Desktop\bbb.py", line 17, in 
>       cv2.imshow('frame',frame) error: ......\opencv-2.4.13.2\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:269: error:
>   (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

I am new to this and could not find the solution. Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try uncommenting `#gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: Similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python).

Comment: sorry about my first comment! It looks like OpenCV can't find your camera. Try unplugging it and plugging it back in or restarting your PC.