# how to resize frame of ip camera opened in python opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, size, ip-camera

i cant seem to resize the frame output of my ip camera opened in opencv python3

```
    import cv2

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.13/1')

    cap.set(3, 176)
    cap.set(4, 144)

    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

outputting a large frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue looks very similar to other questions posted here
Try to take a look on this one and see if it can helps you: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python)

Basically you must check if :

1. your camera drivers support this feature
2. the property codes you use for setting the output resolution match the ones expected from the vendor drivers
3. the resolution is actually supported by your camera

An alternative workaround, very easy but consider it as worst case, could be resize the frame after the aquisition:

```
success,image = cap.read()
resize = cv2.resize(image, (176, 144))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is working now.. sorry took tooooo long to check. but appreciate the answer so much