# Is it possible to get extremal values of video settings by means of OpenCV itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, camera

I'm going to calibrate GUI elements (Tkinter's Scale indeed) for some video settings.

Can I get the maxima and minima of the parameters of the USB-camera with OpenCV?

One can easily set and get the camera parameters ([Setting Camera Parameters in OpenCV/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python)),
for example, with the following commands:

```
videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print('Brightness:', videoCapture.get(10))
```

and so on.
But the different cameras can have not equal ranges of some parameter. For example the Genius Slim 320 USB-camera
has the brightness range 0...255, but an another USB-camera has the brightness range -64...+64.
Is it possible to get the maxima and minima of the USB-camera parameters (such as a brightness, contrast and so on) by means of OpenCV itself?
Or it is possible from the camera driver only?

Of course, I suppose that I can set some parameter and then get it and check, does it change, and I can do it in some loop, and so I shell find the maximum (or the minimum) of this parameter.

Finally I had wrote the following function:

```
def getExtr(mode, step):
   state0 = videoCapture.get(mode)
   param0 = state0
   sign = 0
   while sign==0:
      param0 += step
      videoCapture.set(mode, param0)
      param = videoCapture.get(mode)
      if param0 != param:
         sign=1
   videoCapture.set(mode, state0)  # return parameter to initial setting
   return param
```

and I use it:

```
import cv2

videoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

print('Max brightness: ', getExtr(10,  1))
print('Min brightness: ', getExtr(10, -1))
```

It works fine, but it takes several seconds to get all maxima and minima for all camera parameters allowed by OpenCV.

But may be exists a much simpler (and faster) method (standard for OpenCV)?

Comment: I just ran into this and have tried your same solution, again - it takes quite a while. I noticed the values set to a "default" if set to a value that is too high or too low, but the default is always the same, it doesn't limit it to a max/min.