# How to be OFF the AWB/AE of RaspberryPi Cam ( Raspi4, RaspiCamV2.1, Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi4

I'm using
 - RaspberryPi4
 - Raspberry camera ver2.1
 - Python3
 - OpenCV3
trying to catch a color from movie and success-ed with like [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html),

But because of AWB/AE, sometime misses the target.

I tryed to stop them

1. OpenCVs ".set" [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python)

   --> not supported
2. "raspivid" command

   --> not correct
3. picamera.camera() module

   --> cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    is error.

I couldn't find out the right way.
Hope to help, thank you.

Comment: Of course its possible to miss the target sometimes for a short time. It depends on many things. But you may hold the last coordinate of the target until the next detection.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I'm not big expert, but AFAIK you'd better have turned on AWB/AE. You should read more about taking picture programtically with camera. It has many dependency, but general flow is to "trigger search focus" -> "lock focus" -> "trigger search exposure" -> "lock exposure" -> "trigger search WB" -> "lock WB" -> "take picture". If any of steps failed or timeouted, then you have to handle it properly.

Comment: it is unclear what you wan to do exactly : are you trying to turn off auto white balance and auto exposure ? if so then why are you trying to convert BGR to HSV ?

Comment: Thank you for rel. to anotoine, BGR to HSV is easier to find the color with choice HUE.

Comment: [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) is aimost same as my code.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it myself

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np
import picamera
import time

from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera

def detect(img):
    hsv_min = np.array([20,100,80])
    hsv_max = np.array([27,255,255])
    masked = cv2.inRange(img, hsv_min, hsv_max)

    return masked


def main():
    #camera mode
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 20
    camera.awb_mode = 'fluorescent'
    camera.awb_gains = 4
    camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
    capture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

    # allow the camera to warmup
    time.sleep(0.1)

    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(capture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
        image = frame.array
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        mask = detect(hsv)

        label = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask)

        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        capture.truncate(0)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

thank you for cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

There are properties to control auto white balance ([CAP_PROP_AUTO_WB](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da762391cbaa101c4015e6a935aa0cfc95)) and auto exposure ([CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da5c790a640b290f73fcd279e8bbaf0f13)).

As far as I know, you can use them in python (instead of raw integer value like in the code you linked to) :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE,0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_WB,0)
```

But be aware that this doesn't work with all backends, at least GStreamer doesn't provide a way to control camera parameter, with V4L2 it depends on the camera driver.

You can force the API to use by passing it at a second argument to [`VideoCapture`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) constructor.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, I tried the way. You are right that my camea (= raspberrypi cam)  may be not supported cap.set(15,0)/cap.set(16,0) because it doesn't work.
capset(10,*) worked.