# How do I access my USB camera using OpenCV with python?

Tags: python, opencv, usb-camera

I am having trouble accessing my USB camera using OpenCV with python.

I get the following error message which I understand means no frame was captured?

```
error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

My camera is the following: https://www.gophotonics.com/products/scientific-industrial-cameras/point-grey-research-inc/45-571-cm3-u3-50s5m-cs

Simple code as below. Any thoughts? Some help I'll appreciate

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try putting '1' instead of '0' in VideoCapture. Like, cv2.VideoCapture(1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not think its an indexing problem,  I have tried iterating up to index 500 and none work...

Comment: Is your usb camera working normally with your computer, without trying to access it from python? Like using some default usb option to access it. Just to check if it's compatible and it works fine normally.

Comment: It works using spinview, program provided by the company

Answer (score 7):

The `camera index` most of the time is `0` as default with computers which come with an integrated camera, but if you're plugging a USB camera, its `camera index` could be `1` or `2`, you can try with both of them.

But if you wanna get all `camera index` available, you can use the following simple script to find out:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

all_camera_idx_available = []

for camera_idx in range(10):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_idx)
    if cap.isOpened():
        print(f'Camera index available: {camera_idx}')
        all_camera_idx_available.append(camera_idx)
        cap.release()
```

The result would be a `list` like: `[0,1,2,...]` with all camera index available.

But if you're using a USB camera you have to keep in mind that some `OpenCV` functions won't work, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not think its an indexing problem, I have tried iterating up to index 500 and none work...