# How to configure the Field of View of Logitech BRIO 4K Stream Edition webcam?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, logitech

How can I configure the Field of View of the logitech brio4k webcam through python and openCV?
I already found this post: [Setting Camera Parameters in OpenCV/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420748/setting-camera-parameters-in-opencv-python) . Unfortunately, FOV is not mentioned there.
The brio4K webcam offers FOV of 65, 78 and 90°.

Comment: that's not configurable. FoV is implied by your choice of resolution. webcams have "modes", consisting of binning and cropping. you pick a mode, and that's that. opencv lets you pick by resolution+FPS+pixfmt, but that's it. -- in general, a camera sensor's full resolution image can be cropped and binned. that's how lower resolutions are achieved. cropping affects FoV. cropping need not maintain aspect ratio. different crops, for the same binning (or no binning), have identical "focal length" in pixels. only binning affects the focal length. -- FoV is affected by cropping, but not by binning.

Comment: probe the device with ffmpeg/ffprobe. query the "modes". ffmpeg wiki has the magic spells.