# Using iPhone continuity camera with openCV gets different resolutions

Tags: python, iphone, opencv

I have two Python scripts both have the same set width and height attributes however it sometimes happens to be the case that they totally neglect that and display a different resolution (cropped somehow). I can't find anything online and there is no clear documentation or project already done like this so if anyone can help me understand what's going on with the iPhone camera it would help a lot.
Here is the code I'm using in one of the files (the other one is the same with some extra functions for drawing on the feed):

```
import cv2

# camera id & resolution
camera_id = 0
width, height = 720, 1080

# initialize camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)
cap.set(3, width)
cap.set(4, height)

# get live camera feed
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Original image ", img)

    # Quit when "Q" is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# close all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried reseting my phone and also trying to find existing issues online.

Comment: Did you check if the enumerated properties are the same for iOS camera? Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433221/16815358