# How to improve the image quality before the image processing start in javacv or opencv?

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv, javacv

I have an image with 400x400 image to identify different components from it. But when I try to identify components using that most of time it doesn't provide correct answers. So I need to know whether there are some kind of methods in javacv or opencv to improve the quality of the image or increase the size of the image without effecting to its quality ?

This is the sample image that I use. (This is the maximum size that I can get and I can't use any photo editing softwares in the project, because it's dynamically generated image.)

[image]

In my image processing I need to identify squares and rectangles that connects those squares. And specially I need to get the width and height of those using pixel values.

Comment: Are you sure of no way to get a much more better image?

Comment: Yes I generated this image using kabeja package. So that's the maximum quality that I can get. I need to improve the quality of this image using javacv methods.So I trying to increasing the size of the image and then I hope it might be able to use image processing techniques extract the information.

Comment: @Abid is it possible to increase the size of the image in opencv ? I mean to scale the image ?

Answer (score 3):

You can scale it to any size, if you can vectorize it... and in your case vestorization is quite simple as you have some simple geometrical objects in image.

So, in my view your approach should be like this:

1. detect edges in the image with a high threshold (as you have very distinct objects)
2. vectorize them
3. scale them to any size

You should also look at the following link: [Increasing camera capture resolution in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287/increasing-camera-capture-resolution-in-opencv).

Comment: First though, kick up contrast and sharpen. That will instantly bring out the edges. To edge enhance, take the discovered edges and darken them and even their surrounding pixels with a min filter.  That should do the trick in establishing clear probabalistic boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

If you stick to image processing the easiest way to do it is to apply an equalizeHist(). This will increase contrast and will improve subsequent steps.

**But**, and this is a biiiig 'but', why are you doing it? Just reading this post, I saw another solution, and a quick google proved me I am right:

> Kabeja is a Java library for parsing, processing and converting
>   Autodesk's DXF format. You can use Kabeja from the CommandLine or
>   embed into your application. All parsed data are accessible with the
>   DOM-like API.

That means you can extract directly all the data you want from that image in a text format. Probably something like  "at position x, y there is a transistor, or whatever." So **why** would you render that file into an image, then analyse that image to extract the components?

If you do it for school (I know that many school projects are like this) I would recommend you to find a real problem to solve, and propose it to your teacher. You will be happier to do something that is not complete nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

vectorizing the image is best option I guess as suggested by [mocap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989091/mocap).
you can also use enhancement tools like sharpening, saturating etc.