# Setting frame size of QuickCam Pro 3000 with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, logitech

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.6 to grab images with my old Logitech QuickCam Pro 3000 webcam. Using `VideoCapture::set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, ... )` I'm not able to set the value of the width (idem for the height). `set(...)` always returns `false`.

Is it normal?

**P.S.** I'm on Linux (*kubuntu*) and it seems to use V4L.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing camera capture resolution in OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287/increasing-camera-capture-resolution-in-opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your camera was not initialized properly. The following code works for me.

```
using namespace cv;

[...]

VideoCapture capture(0);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);
```

I experimented with it a bit and found the following issues:

1. `capture.set` returns 0 if `capture` was not initialized.
2. `capture.set` returns 0 if camera is busy (another process using it).

It is not guaranteed that calling `VideoCapture::set` will change camera resolution to your desired resolution. For example, with my Logitech HD Pro Webcam C290, setting resolution to 640x480 and 1920x1080 works. But when I try 1024x768, `VideoCapture::set` returns true, but actual resolution is set to 960x720. So, check the actual resolution after reading a frame.

Comment: To say the truth, I did exactly what you're suggesting. But `set()` returned 0 in both case. I'll try a little spike solution as soon as possible to experiment a little more with that. Maybe I'll try with the Python interface which will be more efficient for testing/prototyping. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I tried with Python and I think the camera was "busy". I retried then it worked. I could set WIDTH, HEIGHT, BRIGHTNESS, SATURATION, GAIN, CONTRAST, EXPOSURE but **not** FPS. Thanks again.